# I can't output an array from a user's input

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to create a program which asks a user to input a list of names and each name should be added to an array and the user can only input 10 names maximum and if they try to input more a message needs to come up and say that they have already have ten names and then output those ten names. I am struggling with the outputs

```
let inputArray = [];
let size = 11;

for(let i = 0; i < size; i++){

    if (i < size) {
        inputArray[i] = prompt("Please enter the name of 10 people 
                                 you would like to invite to a party" 
                                 + (i+1));
    } else if (i = 11) {
        console.log("You have already invited 10 people");
    }
}
console.log(inputArray);
```

Comment: Be careful of `if(i = 11)` (assignment rather than comparison)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
let inputArray = [];
let maxSize = 10;

for (let i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
  let name = prompt(`Please enter name ${i+1} of ${maxSize}:`);
  if (name !== null) {
    inputArray.push(name);
  } else {
    console.log("You have cancelled the input process.");
    break;
  }
}

if (inputArray.length === maxSize) {
  console.log("You have reached the maximum number of names.");
} 

console.log("The names you have entered are: ");
console.log(inputArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out and see if it works for you.

```
let limit = 3
let arr = new Array(limit), size = 11;

for(let i=0; i<size; i++){
    let inpttext = prompt("Please enter the name of 10 people.");
    if(i < arr.length){
        arr.push(inpttext);
    }else{
        console.log("You have already invited 10 people.")
        break;
    }   
}

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: You can add, null checkers and other conditions inside the loop if you like.